Building Simulink Design off schematic
I am new to using simulink and am after building this model in the picture below. The only values which are not constants is K(t), and  θ_a(t) which are inputs. Ultimately I'm confused with what the arrows between the block are? Are they indicating that the output of the block is being multiplied with the next block?
Then in the last flow where the input is θ_a(t) is that being multiplied with 1/k11t0s?
Any clarification is appreciated.


Multiplication is correct if you represent functions by their Laplace transforms. Otherwise s stands for the differentiation operator, so that 1/(1+c*s) stands for Y(s)=X(s)/(1+c*s) or y(t)+c*y'(t)=x(t) with x the input, y the output, X,Y their Laplace transforms.
There are elaborate schemes on how to replace s to get a finite difference equation or to transform the whole schema to an ODE system that is solve via standard methods.
